# pg_dump: Show GRANT Statements only

Tags: postgresql, permissions, pg-dump

I executed this manually:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE my_table TO some_user;
```

How can I dump this statement again?

I looked at `pg_dumpd` but only found a way to do a data-only dump or a schema-only dump.

If I do the following, then I get both (CREATE TABLE and GRANT statements)

```
pg_dump --schema-only -t my_table my_db
```

Is there a way to exclude the CREATE statements, and to show the GRANT statements only?

Answer (score 3):

This should work,

```
pg_dump --section=pre-data -d myDb | grep -e '^\(GRANT\|REVOKE\)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say if you want roles infos, you should use `pg_dumpall` with the `--role-only` option.

You might find the documentation on [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-dumpall.html) useful.

Comment: `pg_dumpall --roles-only` does dump `CREATE ROLE` and `ALTER ROLE`. This question is about dumping the `GRANT` statements. Your answer is correct, but it is the answer to a different question :-)

Comment: Your right, I'm wrong... Sorry...

Comment: It's still a useful answer, though.